# brew install mongodb error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install' Mac OSX Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, mongodb, osx-lion, homebrew

I am not sure why I'm getting this error:

```
$ brew install mongodb
==> Downloading http://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.4.tgz
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/var/log/mongodb
```

So I try to run it with sudo:

```
$ sudo brew install mongodb
Password:
Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install'
```

If I try to create the file myself I get this:

```
Error: File exists - /usr/local/var/log/mongodb
```

It gets even more interesting when you read this thread on homebrew's github about the error:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9953

They state that brew can't write the file because it's not root, then they say it's because they think it shouldn't run as root.

These are the official install instructions, what's up?

If you have a better suggestion for installing it, then I'll forget about homebrew.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The lazy (brew) way:

```
ls -al /usr/local/bin/brew #confirm brew ownership
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/bin/brew
sudo brew install mongodb
sudo chown <your user>:<your group> /usr/local/bin/brew  #revert ownership
```

The non-brew way:

- Download mongodb distribution from 10gen: http://www.mongodb.org/downloads
- Install files in /usr/local/bin/
- Create a config file in /etc/mongo.conf (minimum, tell it where to store data, and probably tell it to bind only to localhost): http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration
- Create a startup script that calls `mongod -f /etc/mongo.conf`

Comment: i will go with the lazy way. i appreciate the effort, very informative.

Comment: i really like home brew package management, are there any advantages to not using home brew and just downloading manually as outlined above?

Comment: you can manage which version you're running more easily (and use the development releases), and you end up understanding how mongodb works a little better. but for everyday developer use, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Would you recommend that I create a `mongodb` folder inside `/usr/local/bin/` or rather just copy all the mongo files (mongo, mongod, etc) directly into `/usr/local/bin/`?

Comment: how do I know what I do for <your user>:<your group>

Comment: What this line do? "sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/bin/brew", what is this "root:wheel"? When I run "ls -al /usr/local/bin/brew" I get "-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  1363 15 Nov 05:42 /usr/local/bin/brew"

Comment: @franziskux make it root:admin then. sounds like the new versions of mac os have a different admin account name.

Comment: Why should we revert ownership? Why don't we keep it this way?

Answer (score 4):

I keep hitting this same problem over and over with different brew packages *(today it was ImageMagick)*, so I keep coming back to this page.  I'm just going to leave my version of the above instructions for myself, and maybe someone else will find it handy too

```
ls -al `which brew` # note user/group
sudo chown root:wheel `which brew`
sudo brew install <package name>
sudo chown <your user>:<your group> `which brew` # revert ownership
```

using `which brew` in back ticks substitutes your path to brew.

*(and how do I escape backticks?)*

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting this error before realizing-- I WAS SUDO SU'd!

In other words, I had a root prompt and was trying to run brew install . Do not try to install using brew if your command prompt has a # at the end.

I feel dumb about it, but maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: just ran into the same problem. Thanks for the hint