# Failing while running `brew install

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, homebrew, libxml2

I am trying to re-install Nokogiri dependencies with homebrew following the steps described [here](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#homebrew_09). I had nokogiri working fine before, but had to remove macports to make some space on my mac.

Running into errors at the first step:

```
$ brew install libxml2 libxslt
Warning: Your Xcode (3.2.2) is outdated
Please install Xcode 3.2.6.
==> Downloading ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
                                                                       0.0%
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1448)
Error: Download failed: ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Is the warning about Xcode version significant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant message above seemed to be `Warning: Failed to create the file`.

Tried to create the `/Library/Caches/Homebrew/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz` file manually, and got a `Permission denied` error.

Changed the ownership of the folder to my username:group with

```
sudo chown <username>:<group> /Library/Caches/Homebrew/
```

With that change, the `brew install` step worked successfully!

Note: The answers to [brew install mongodb error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install' Mac OSX Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424872/brew-install-mongodb-error-cowardly-refusing-to-sudo-brew-install-mac-osx-lio) helped in figuring out the problem.

Comment: I had to use chown -R because just using chown on /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ was giving me Permission denied - /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/ error