# Trying to install 1st MEAN app but get Error: Permission denied - (mongod.conf, /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf)

Tags: mongodb, meanjs

I've been trying to install my 1st MEAN app. I installed mongoDB via home brew. using https://stackoverflow.com/a/10425148/3915717

Here is as far as I got:

```
Before you install the dependencies and fire up the server we can help you with setting up your first admin user.
? Cool, bring it on: y
? Please provide your email so we can create your first admin user: b@v.dd
? Please provide your username so we can create your first admin user: n
    Error Connecting to database: { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }
```

`grep mongo /etc/passwd` returns nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you started the `MongoD` Server? Make sure that it's running. This error generally occurs because `MongoD` is not running due to which the client application isn't able to connect to it.

Make sure you have `MongoDB` installation directory path saved in your `PATH` environment variable. Then fire up command prompt and type in

```
mongod
```

This will start `MongoD` Server on it's default port `27017`

This should rectify your connection error. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot? Are you sure the MongoD Server is running? Coz this error generally occurs when the MongoD server is not running.

Comment: opps sorry, I see this: `2016-02-28T09:31:07.657+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating`

Comment: I have drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  68 28 Feb 20:31 /data/db/

Comment: and now get `[initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
`

Comment: I got it working, I changed permision of that folder to $USER